# Mongo aggregate with multiple aggregation types

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to aggregate the following data

```
- Country: One, Car: Volvo, Name: Smith, Price: 100
- Country: One, Car: BMW,   Name: Smith, Price: 200
- Country: Two, Car: Romeo, Name: Joe,   Price: 50
- Country: Two, Car: KIA,   Name: Joe,   Price: 110
- Country: Two, Car: KIA,   Name: Joe,   Price: 90
```

(Names are unique, each one owns cars in single country)

The results, I expect (pluralization is not required):

```
- Name: Smith, Type: Volvos, Country: One, Val: 1   // Count of car-type
- Name: Smith, Type: BMWs,   Country: One, Val: 1
- Name: Smith, Type: Total,  Country: One, Val: 2   // Count of all his cars
- Name: Smith, Type: Price,  Country: One, Val: 300 // Total car price
- Name: Joe,   Type: Romeos, Country: Two, Val: 1 
- Name: Joe,   Type: KIAs,   Country: Two, Val: 2
- Name: Joe,   Type: Total,  Country: Two, Val: 3
- Name: Joe,   Type: Price,  Country: Two, Val: 250
```

E.g. this is a pivotized data version to build a report

```
Country | Name   | Volvos | BMWs | Romeos | KIAs | Total | Price 
----------------------------------------------------------------
One     | Smith  |      1 |    1 |        |      |     2 |   300
----------------------------------------------------------------
Two     | Joe    |        |      |      1 |    2 |     3 |   250
        | Other  |      ? |    ? |     ... etc
```

I'm thinking if aggregation framework in mongo can handle this, or should i go with hardcore map-reduce?

Comment: Try this using aggregation. bcoz if data become large then it is difficult to go with hardcore map reduce

Comment: @Mayuri Map reduce and aggregation are two different things for two totally different pruposes, MR should not be run inline to your own application for example

Comment: The main question is that I am not sure this is implementable with AF.

Comment: Is there a dynamic amount of car types?

Comment: @Sammaye yes, You can expect anything there. But there's no need to correct them -- it should go as is

Comment: I think your gonna need two queries here unless you calc the totla for each row manually in your client code (which could work quite well), it is just I do not think you cna get each total of a car and then the grand total like that in the aggregation framework, you might with $cond if the list of cars were not dynamic

Comment: @Sammaye can I run two aggregation queries and append second results to the same collection as the first one?

Comment: Doesn't seem like it: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/ only replace but you can sort both by the same thing so that you can pick at the same index, i.e. it is very much like picking form only one collection

Comment: Actusally there is a way of doing this in one query, you can $push the cars to a subdocument from there do your totals, hmm question is would that be the performant way to do this? hmm

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly the result you prescribe, but actually in a kind of MongoDB way:

```js
db.cars.aggregate([
   { "$group": {
       "_id": {
           "name": "$Name",
           "type": "$Car"
       },
       "Country": { "$first": "$Country" },
       "CarCount": { "$sum": 1 },
       "TotalPrice": { "$sum": "$Price" }
   }},
   { "$group": {
       "_id": "$_id.name",
       "cars": {
           "$push": {
               "type": "$_id.type",
               "country": "$Country",
               "carCount": "$CarCount",
               "TotalPrice": "$TotalPrice"
            }
        },
        "TotalPrice": { "$sum": "$TotalPrice" }
   }}
])
```

Which gives you:

```js
{
    "_id" : "Smith",
    "cars" : [
            {
                    "type" : "BMW",
                    "country" : "One",
                    "carCount" : 1,
                    "TotalPrice" : 200
            },
            {
                    "type" : "Volvo",
                    "country" : "One",
                    "carCount" : 1,
                    "TotalPrice" : 100
            }
    ],
    "TotalPrice" : 300
}
{
    "_id" : "Joe",
    "cars" : [
            {
                    "type" : "KIA",
                    "country" : "Two",
                    "carCount" : 2,
                    "TotalPrice" : 200
            },
            {
                    "type" : "Romeo",
                    "country" : "Two",
                    "carCount" : 1,
                    "TotalPrice" : 50
            }
    ],
    "TotalPrice" : 250
}
```

Comment: Hey, mayabe I can also push { type: 'Total' } in cars, and the unwind results to get exactly matching collection? Is that possible?

Comment: @RustemMustafin not really he ran into the same problem as I did, if you have a car form two different countries by the same guy these totals won't match up

Comment: @Sammaye this is valid, because I stated that `each one owns cars in single country`

Comment: @RustemMustafin ah ok so it is actually ok if we don't group by country?

Comment: @NeilLunn @Sammaye `one person owns cars only in one country`, e.g. if you see Joe -- USA, then Joe will always be USA. That's why the "optmimzation" $first: Country is valid.
However in general case it might get wrong, I'll try to test if possible

Comment: Thanks for both of you, will post the solution soon. Should say it will take the best ideas from this conversation

Answer (score 1):

There might be some trick to doing this however, with a variable number of types I do not believe you can get this all in one aggregation query, however, you can get the entire table in two.

I should mention that the totals can be calculated client side which should be quite fast as well.

I should also note that the aggregation framework currently has no way to "merge" two outputs: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/ but you can sort both results to be ordered the same.

First you want your total (if you are doing this through aggregation framework):

```
db.cars.aggregate({
    {$group: {
        _id: {
            Country: '$country',
            Name: '$Name'
        },
        car_count: {$sum: 1},
        value_total: {$sum: '$Val'}
    }},
    {$sort: {_id: 1}} // we now sort by the country and name
})
```

So now you want your per car totals:

```
db.cars.aggregate({
    {$group: {
        _id: {
            Country: '$country',
            Name: '$Name',
            Type: '$Type'
        },
        sort_key: { // We add this so we can sort the same as the totals
            Country: '$Country',
            Name: '$Name'
        },
        car_count: {$sum: 1},
        value_total: {$sum: '$Val'}
    }},
    {$sort: {sort_key: 1}} // we now sort by the country and name
})
```

Now the what you can, in JavaScript for example is iterate the first set of results, your totals, iterating the detail results from the other aggregation in a nested loop printing it all out.

This would likely be faster than Map Reduce but another alternative is to update the aggregated collection once every so often using Map Reduce and just from there pick out. This means that the results will not be in realtime (maybe delayed by 5 mins) but it will be super speedy.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregation should be just fine for this.
Easiest as 2 separate commands...
If your collection was called cars you could run something like this:

```
db.cars.aggregate([{$group:{_id:{"Country":"$Country","Name":"$Name"},"sum":{$sum:1},"price":{$sum:"$Price"}}}])


db.cars.aggregate([{$group:{_id:{"Country":"$Country","Name":"$Name","Car":"$Car"},"sum":{$sum:1},"price":{$sum:"$Price"}}}])
```

Comment: The results of your command are not what I expect: there are no *count of all cars per person*, and no *total car price per person*.

Comment: Now we are missing counts of cars per person with given type (see, Joe has 2 KIAs and 3 cars in total).

Comment: It is still unclear for me how to save two results in one collection.
I also need to add Country, Name and Car from _id to the root document.